# How many Firebase projects can I create per google account? How many apps can I attach to a single Firebase project?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I'm using Firebase as my backend service. 
I'm working on a project where the possible clients are more than 100 clients.
Each one will have an Android and IOS apps. Making the total of apps 200 app.

I know that the maximum projects that could be created per Google account are 6 projects. Maximum number of apps (IOS, Android and WEB) are almost 30 apps.

What are the possible solutions in order to create that many apps ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the number of *free* Firebase projects you can have per account. The limit depends on your account, and is not the same for everyone. There is no such limit on the number of *paid* projects.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you don't need a separate project for every *instance* of the app out there. In fact, you probably don't need more than one for a whole app's user base. When used with `FirebaseAuth` to authenticate users, a single Cloud Firestore or Firebase Realtime Database should handle all your data.